# How to allow only A-Za-z chars

Tags: .net, vb.net

I tried below code:

```
 Private Sub txtName_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtName.KeyPress
  ' allow upper and lower case A-Z, and backspace
  If Not Chr(KeyAscii) Like "[A-Za-z]" And KeyAscii <> 8 Then KeyAscii = 0
 End Sub
```

But it gives:

> 'KeyAscii' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Any idea on how to allow alphabet only ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you tried to translate a VB6 code verbatim. You need to re-learn the language, VB.NET is completely different in anything but name.

In your particular case, `KeyAscii` has been replaced by the [`KeyPressedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx) which has two members: `KeyChar` and `Handled`.

Furthermore, .NET distinguishes between characters and strings (= collection of characters), you cannot simply take a character and apply the `Like` operator to it, nor should you.

Instead, do the following:

```
If Character.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then
    e.Handle = True
End If
```

Setting `Handled` to `True` has generally the same effect as setting `KeyAscii` to 0 in VB6 (read the documentation!).

Furthermore, since you’re obviously just switching, make sure to enable both `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` in the project options, as well as making it the default for further projects in the Visual Studio settings. This helps catching quite a lot of errors for you.

Finally, **this code is bad for usability**. It’s generally accepted that fields should *not* constrain user input in such a way (and it’s also not safe: what if the user uses copy&paste to enter invalid text?). Instead, you should test the validity of the input in the textbox’ [`Validating` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx), since it exists this very purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following Regular expression :

```
Dim reg_exp As New RegExp
reg_exp.Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]*$"
If reg_exp.Test(txtName.Text.Trim()) Then
   MessageBox.Show("Input name is correct")
Else
   MessageBox.Show("Input name is not correct")
End If
```

Comment: Nooo, you shouldn’t. Why? It solves a problem that doesn’t exist (`Like` works just as well, but actually neither works on characters). Furthermore, code of the form `If Something Then Return True Else Return False` is just bad. You should write `Return Something` directly, no need for the redundant `If`.

Comment: I just wanted to show him an example of using regular expressions , ok ?!

Comment: Nevertheless, the code is still needlessly complex since `Like` as in OP’s code works just as well. Also, no, your code does *not* work – you’re probably used to PHP where you need to put the regular expressions between delimiters (`'/…/'`) but that doesn’t work in .NET.

Comment: Just write "you may use RegEx" and that will be absolutely suitable. Anyway +1 because seems that it leads OP's thoughts.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thx about mentioning '/.../' ! It's a problem comming out of programming in multiple languages ;) I edited my code to work in .NET

Answer (score 1):

Where is KeyAscii defined? It looks like it's out of scope.

As you can't just pass it in as a parameter, try declaring it globally first. Then you should be able to access it inside your method.

Disclaimer: Whilst I've used it before, my knowledge of VB.NET is very limited.

Comment: Even if you declared it, it wouldn’t have a meaningful value …

Comment: You're right. This is just my inexperience with VB.NET talking. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

Dim keyAscii As Char
keyAscii = e.KeyChar

        If keyAscii > Chr(64) And keyAscii < Chr(91) Then
        'char is A-Z

    End If

    If keyAscii > Chr(96) And keyAscii < Chr(123) Then
        'char is a-z
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you insist on doing manually you should at least use `AndAlso` instead of `And`: the first is a logical operator, the latter is a bitwise operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) < 65) _
 Or (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122) Then
e.Handled = True
End If
If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
e.Handled = False
End If
```

Comment: It is better if you add some explanation to explain why your code solves the issue.